# Angular click checkbox without checking it

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

I have this checkbox in my Angular project:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="approve_required" (change)="onClick($event,'approve_required',data)" [checked]="isChecked">
```

When the checkbox is clicked, I actually first want to check if it is even allowed to set it on checked. Because if not, the checkbox should remain unchecked and instead a modal will open. The way it is now, it is clicked and appears as checked immediately even if I set "isChecked" false after checking a condition in my onClick function.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In template (html),

```
<input type="checkbox" id="approve_required" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (ngModelChange)="onClick($event,'approve_required',data)">
```

In ts,

```
onClick(value, value1, data){
  this.isChecked = false;
  // open modal here
}
```

Comment: This still makes the checkbox appear as checked. As soon as I click it, it will display as checked not matter what the value of the isChecked variable is. But I'm afraid there is now way of clicking a checkbox without having it displayed as checked after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the checkbox:

```
(click)="$event.preventDefault()"
```